# Can we use vuforia for embedding markers into pre-recorded videos instead of a live camera feed?

Tags: augmented-reality, arkit, vuforia, arcore

I am currently working on a service to update the content of the video bases on the markers present in the video. I was curious if we can use Vuforia to achieve the same by providing the pre-recorded video as an input to Vuforia instead of the live camera feed from the mobile phone.

Answer (score 0):

**TLDR;** This is not possible because replacing the camera is not a function that neither Vuforia or ARKit expose.

Aside from not exposing the camera both frameworks use a combination of camera input and sensor data *(gyro, accelerometer, compass, altitude, etc)* to calculate the camera/phone's position *(translation/rotation)* relative to the marker image.

The effect you are looking for is image tracking and rendering within a video feed. You should consider OpenCV for the feature point tracking, or some computer vision library. With regard to rendering there's three options SceneKit, Metal, or OpenGL. Following Apple's lead you could use SceneKit for the rendering, similar to how ARKit handles the sensor inputs and uses SceneKit for rendering. If you are ambitious and want to control the rendering as well you could use Metal or OpenGL.